# Why is Chrome making two requests to my app?

Tags: google-chrome, http, flask, http-headers, ogg

I have a Flask application that returns server-generated Ogg Vorbis audio.

```
resp = make_response(out.getvalue())  # out is a StringIO()
resp.headers['Content-Type'] = 'audio/ogg'
return resp
```

When I request this in Chrome, it behaves strangely. After the first request is completed, the Chrome audio player displays, and then the second request is sent. Once that one is complete, the audio begins to play.

There are only a few differences between the requests:

**Request 1**

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

**Request 2**

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0
Range: bytes=0-8397
```

What's strange about the `Range` header in the second request is that the `Content-Length` of the response is 8398.

The response headers are the same on both requests.

```
Content-Length: 8398
Content-Type: audio/ogg
Date: Sun, 10 May 2015 18:35:09 GMT
Server: Werkzeug/0.9.6 Python/2.7.9
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Can you also post the HTML / JS code corresponding to the loading of the audio file ?

Comment: There is none; I'm requesting the audio URL directly.

Comment: My educated guess is that Chrome first does file type discovery (this is the first request). Once it figures out that it deals with an audio file, it starts requesting ranges to provide playback without waiting for the whole file to download.

Comment: @RomanK is correct.    I have seen similar behavior with PDF files.